# petite-vue Directives with async function calls

Tags: javascript, async-await, petite-vue

I've need to create a petite-vue directive that allows for async calls...however, I get the TypeScript error:

> Argument of type '(ctx: DirectiveContext) => Promise'
> is not assignable to parameter of type 'Directive'. Type
> 'Promise' is not assignable to type 'void | (() => void)'.

```
const app = PetiteVue.createApp({ count: 1 });
app.directive("my-dir", async ctx => {
    const response = await someGlobalAsync();
    // use response to do something...
});
app.mount("#myElement");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that has this issue, I solved by changing original d.ts...

```
interface PetiteVueApp {
    directive(name: string, def?: Directive<Element> | undefined): Directive<Element> | any;
}
interface Directive<T = Element> {
    (ctx: DirectiveContext<T>): (() => void) | void;
}
```

To:

```
interface PetiteVueApp {
    directive(name: string, def?: AsyncDirective<Element> | Directive<Element> | undefined): Directive<Element> | any;
}
interface AsyncDirective<T = Element> {
    (ctx: DirectiveContext<T>): Promise<(() => void) | void>;
}
interface Directive<T = Element> {
    (ctx: DirectiveContext<T>): (() => void) | void;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a reactive variable for what you need to process n the directive - and call an async function that changes the reactive variable asynchronously.

Comment: You don't happen to have a easy sample of this do you?

Comment: Be a bit more specific about what are you trying to achieve, and I can try to come up with a sample.

Comment: Sorry, missed this notification.  But I'm not sure what you are asking for more than what my question already demonstrates.  To be a bit more specific, I made a directive that upon initialization (it won't really have any reactivity) it needs to call an api via async/await.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Why do you need your callback function for your directive be async? Explain it, please. I think it's likely that there is another way to achieve what you're trying to achieve. What are you trying to achieve by making the callback function async?